# Sql Azure and JDBC connection pool

Tags: jdbc, azure-sql-database, connection-pooling, hikaricp

Does SQL Azure allow 3-rd party connection pool like HikariCP or BoneCP?
We configured HikariCP it works when we just run app but later db doesnt response on request. Is it HikariCP issue or it's common connection poool issue and no need spending more time on investigation?

```
 HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setMaximumPoolSize(50);

    config.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    config.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
    config.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
    config.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));


    config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", env.getProperty("jdbc.cachePrepStmts"));
    config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", env.getProperty("jdbc.prepStmtCacheSize"));
    config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", env.getProperty("jdbc.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit"));
    config.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", env.getProperty("jdbc.useServerPrepStmts"));
```

Answer (score 2):

See this SQL [Azure page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336245.aspx) re: Connection Constraints.

> Maximum allowable durations are subject to change depending on the resource usage. 
>   A logged-in session that has been idle for 30 minutes will be terminated 
>   automatically. ***We strongly recommend that you use the connection pooling*** and 
>   always close the connection when you are finished using it so that the unused 
>   connection will be returned to the pool. For more information about connection 
>   pooling, see Connection Pooling.

See if any of [these errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/4cff491e-9359-4454-bd7c-fb72c4c452ca#bkmk_throt_errors) match up to your logs.  Search that page for "terminated" and "busy" to find error codes that might be relevant to your issue.

I would suggest setting the `maxLifetime` property in HikariCP to 15 minutes, and the `idleTimeout` to 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing on the SQL Azure side that would prohibit you from using a 3rd party connection pool. My guess is that the connection failed between the server and the client and the client didn't remove the connection from the pool.

Moving forward, I'd ensure that whichever 3-rd part connection pool you end up using tests that the connection exists before taking it out of the pool for use.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I dropped pool and issue disappeared. I tried configured removing idle connection on HikariCP but it didn't work